# Selection of Database to insert millions of rows everyday to plot graph for each user

Tags: database-design, architecture, scalability, system-design

I am writing a micro-service that needs to store and retrieve large amounts of net-worth vs time data to plot graph.

Basically I need to store large amount of data through cron for each user's net-worth.

There are 20K mutual funds in which user can invest. Currently, there are 80 million users out of which 20 million have invested into multiple mutual funds. These numbers are growing rapidly.

Value of mutual funds is updated daily in database. Using latest value of mutual fund, net-worth of all the users are updated.

Now my challenge is to create scalable design to store ***(user_id, networth, date)*** everyday to plot graph from the time user made his first investment.

My questions are the following:

1. What database should I use?
2. Once database has been selected what are the ways to achieve scalability to insert ~100 million records daily.

**UPDATE** :
Data needs to be stored since the first investment made by user. For simplicity you can assume its 5 years for every user.

Open to any Database. Would prefer Graph Database.

Thank you.

Comment: It does not look like very massive data set - one instance of such tuple can be stored as 24 bytes (assuming user id is a long), so 100mm is just ~2.2Gb. You need to give more details about what your requirements are. What's the timeframe you expect for this 100mm records to be written (during a day, 1h window etc)? How are these records generated - in batch, ticking, etc.? How plotting will work - is it interactive, or it's ok to wait for it? etc.

Comment: Timeframe is not an issue. Records are generated in batch. Yes, plotting needs to be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the new data gets generated on a daily basis for each user and as it is mentioned in the question, the capacity required is to insert 100 million rows on a daily basis. However, it is important to know how far in the past the records need to be preserved in the database? Does the data need to be preserved for a month, a year or five years? Assuming that the trend graph uses data for the past full year, then the total rows required would be 100 million * 365 (days) which comes to 36500 million which comes to 36 billion rows. Assuming that one row occupies 24 bytes, total capacity required is ~ 1TB (rounded off). This would be good to store 1 year of data for all users. At the end of the year, the data can be archived and the full capacity can be re-instated at the beginning of the next year.

Considering that the data does not need ACID support as it is not a transactional data and the data does not have any relationships between different entities, a NoSQL database seems to be a good fit here. Assuming that a batch job will run and insert the updated net worth for all the 100 million users at once, it seems necessary to keep this insert time very short. A key value pair database with fast write support such as Cassandra seems to be a good choice here. The partition key would be userid. Also the nature of the data is such that it is immutable so Cassandra's underlying data storage structure being append only, it makes it even more suitable.

Since the data is immutable, it makes it very suitable for having it cached. Depending on the Cache's capacity, all or some of daily active users' data can be kept in cache to serve the queries that are required to plot the graphs. An LRU Cache can be a good choice.

Note: If NoSQL database is not an option, a relational database with partitioning based on userid also will do the job.

Hope it gives some pointers, if there are usage scenarios apart from the one mentioned in the question, the answer can change.